# make a jQuery plugin with plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to make a tinymce type editor. I want it to be extendable with plugins just like tinymce is. My question is how I could go about loading and using external javascript files in my plugin?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new script tag to pull in the javascript file:

```
YourEditor.loadPlugin = function(url) {
   var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');

   scriptElement.src = url;

   document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
};
```

If the loaded javascript was wrapped in a call to register itself with your editor:

```
YourEditor.registerPlugin("some-plugin", function(YourEditor) {

   /* plugin code */

});
```

In your core code you would declare a function:

```
YourEditor.registerPlugin = function(name, loadFunction) {
   loadFunction (this);

   // fire an event (dummy syntax)
   this.fire('pluginLoaded', name);
};
```

Then you could fire an event out of YourEditor to let the user of the editor know that the plugin 'some-plugin' has been loaded.

Registering the plugins works in a similar manner to jsonp in that it let's you load code from an arbitrary origin based on knowledge of a shared function. It passed a name and a function to call that will set up everything the plugin needs to operate.

Comment: Is there any way you could explain a little more about the **register plugin** part?

Comment: I added some more explanation. If you need anymore help just let me know

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I decided to do:

Use the `jQuery.getScript()` function. Didn't even know it existed.

So here's my code:

```
loadplugins: function() {
        var self = this;
        var settings = self.settings;       
        var plugins = settings.plugins.split(/[\s,]+/);
        var thispath = settings.script_url;

        $.each(plugins, function(i,e) {
            // add .js to the plugin and the path before it
            var thisPlugin = thispath + settings.plugin_dir + e + '.js'; // I'll change this to work with a script or directory

            $.getScript(thisPlugin, function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {

                console.log(data, textStatus, jqxhr);

                self.registerPlugin(data, function() {

                });
            });

        });

        return true;
    },
```